# Дергающаяся анимация

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml, android-animation

Делаю окно с анимацией, все работает почти как надо, но есть момент при котором анимация "дергается", но дергается не сама анимация, а окно в котором все отображается.

Для анимации используется TrasitionManager, и вызывается команда begindelayedtransition, которой на вход первым параметром передается корневой ViewGroup, а вторым AutoTransition

Вероятно, резкое сжатие по высоте происходит у NestedScrollView

Вот ссылка на видео с моей анимацией: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AKhLlOgQua0

```
               <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/address_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    layout="@layout/toolbar"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf='@+id/scroll'
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


                <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/scroll"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar">


                    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        >


                        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                            android:id="@+id/addresses"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/add_address"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
                            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
                            tools:listitem="@layout/recycler_view_item" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/add_address"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="21dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="21dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/background_btn_apply_on"
                            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"
                            android:paddingRight="12dp"
                            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                            android:text="@string/addAddress"
                            android:textAllCaps="false"
                            android:textColor="@color/color_white"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/save"
                            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/addresses" />


                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/save"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="21dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="21dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/background_btn_apply_on"
                            android:text="@string/save"
                            android:textAllCaps="false"
                            android:textColor="@color/color_white"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/add_address" />

                        <android.support.constraint.Group
                            android:id="@+id/addresses_group"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:visibility="visible"
                            app:constraint_referenced_ids="save,add_address,addresses" />

                        <ProgressBar
                            android:id="@+id/addresses_progress"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/addresses_no_connection"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/no_connection"
                            android:visibility="gone"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

                </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Предполагаю что вы добавляете свои Card View прямо в NestedScrollView, если это так вместо NestedScrollView используйте RecyclerView, и уже в него добавляйте Card View.

в любом случае ищите по ключевым словам ***android recyclerview remove item***
https://youtu.be/HMjI7cLsyfw?t=26